# Could I store object with its methods in @ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I wanted to store objects with their methods with @ngrx/entity . Can it cause any problems in application? (Angular 2-7)

**mission.class.ts:**

```js
import { v4 as uuid} from 'uuid';

export class Mission {

  id: string;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;

  constructor (missionTitle: string, completed?: boolean) {
    this.id = uuid();
    this.title = missionTitle;
    this.completed = completed;
  }

  complete() {
    this.completed = true;
  }
}
```

There is the class with method 'complete' mission. I want to save it by @ngrx/entity.

**missions.actions.ts:**

```js
export enum MissionActionTypes {
  AddMission = '[Mission] Add Mission'      
}

export class AddMission implements Action {
  readonly type = MissionActionTypes.AddMission;

  constructor (public payload: { mission: Mission }) {}
}
```

There is the action to add Mission object with its method to @ngrx/store

**missions.reducer.ts:**

```js
export interface MissionsState extends EntityState <Mission> {

}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter <Mission> = createEntityAdapter<Mission>();

export const initialState: MissionsState = adapter.getInitialState();

export function reducer(state = initialState, actions: MissionActions) {

  switch (actions.type) {
  
    case MissionActionTypes.AddMission:
      return adapter.addOne(actions.payload.mission, state);
      
    default: 
      return state;
  }

}
```

When I fetch Mission object from the store using select() I can call 'complete' method of it. But I am Not sure if that approach will cause any problem in the application in the future..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but this doesn't mean you should.

- Actions should be serializable (methods are lost during serialization)
- Selectors should be pure (it should not invoke a side effect, it should only read date from the state)

Comment: "methods are lost during serialization" could you explain what does it means? Did you mean methods of stored objects? Or something else?

Comment: And the main question is **If I will store an objects with their methods it will cause some issue after fetching this objects back** . Sorry if I didn't explain myself clearly at first.

Comment: Yes it will cause issues.

Comment: That question was asked in gitter of ngrx store by my colleague, and Tim Deschryver has mentioned this article https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state . That clearly answers the question.It is **Not Recommended put not serialized objects to redux(ngrx) store**.